# Name and join 2 multi index dataframe after operation is done

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

Have the following multi index data frame, df.

I performed a 20 day moving average operation on the df[‘Close’] with the following code, ma20.

How do I append m20 to df as a multi index data frame?

I should have 3 level 0 columns, ['Adj Close','Close', ‘ma20’], each with the 3 tickers, ['MSFT','AAPL','AMZN'], at level 1 columns.

The answer should also not require me to type out all the tickers manually.

```
import yfinance as yf

df = yf.download(['MSFT','AAPL','AMZN'], start="2022-01-01", end="2022-09-01").loc[:,['Adj Close','Close']]

ma20 = df['Close'].sort_index(ascending=True).rolling(20, min_periods=20).mean()

pd.concat([df,ma20], axis=1)????
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not very elegant solution, but should work, the idea is to specify explicitly the multiindex names for new columns:

```
df[[('Mean', col) for col in ma20.columns]] = ma20
```

**UPDATE:**

If you want to use `concat()` method, you need firstly to add another column index level to `ma20`. The way you can do this looks counter-intuitive up to me:

```
pd.concat((df, pd.concat({'Mean': ma20}, axis=1)), sort=False, axis=1)
```

The purpose of `pd.concat({'Mean': ma20}, axis=1))` is just to add another index level to the columns of `ma20`

Comment: Works great! Do you know of any merge/concat/join methods? Want to check for performance.